# How to pass commit_id as lambda zip file name (s3 object_name) from codepipeline to cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

In order the lambda gets the updated zip file from s3 bucket, whenever I update the file,  I am adding commit-id to zip filename and uploading to s3 bucket. (The s3 bucket versioning is activated as well). Here is what I have done:

I have a CloudFormmation template which creates a lambda-function and the lambda gets the zipped code from a s3 bucket.
For having CI/CD I have created a CodePipeline which in buildpart(buidspec) it creates a zipfile from python script and upload it to s3 bucket , it adds commit-id to zip file name using $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION

CodeBuild:

```
CodeBuild:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-buildzipfile
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildRole.Arn
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: |-
          version: 0.2
          phases:
            install:
              runtime-versions:
                python: 3.8
            build:
              commands:
                - cd src
                - pip install boto3
                - pip install zip_files
                - echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION
                - python codebuildzip.py $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION
                - echo "Uploaded LambdaFunction to S3 bucket."
```

CloudFormation.yml

```
LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties: 
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref 'LambdaZipfileBucket'
        S3Key: lambda_function.zip  ####Here it should be like: lambda_function_{commitid}.zip
      Description: Monitor Lambda Function
      Handler: 'lambda_function.lambda_handler'
      Role: !GetAtt 
        - LambdaExecutionRole
        - Arn
      Runtime: python3.7  
      Environment:
        Variables:
           myvar1: "value1"
```

In the CodePipeline I'm deploying the cloudformation template, here I need to send the lambda zip filename to cloudformation in order Lambda gets the updated S3Key.

```
CodePipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    #checking changes of the template and deploying it.
    Properties:
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref 'ArtifactStoreBucket'
        Type: S3
      Name: !Ref 'PipelineName'
      Stages:
      - Name: Build 
          Actions: 
            - Name: CodeBuild 
              InputArtifacts: 
                - Name: SrcOutput 
              ActionTypeId: 
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS 
                Version: 1 
                Provider: CodeBuild
              Configuration: 
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuild
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput 
              RunOrder: '1'    
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: CreateChangeSet
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: '1'
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SrcOutput
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationExecutionRole.Arn
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
                StackName: !Ref StackName
                ChangeSetName: !Ref ChangeSetName
                TemplatePath: "SrcOutput::templates/CloudFormation.yml"
              RunOrder: '2'  
            - Name: ExecuteChangeSet
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE
                ChangeSetName: !Ref ChangeSetName
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationExecutionRole.Arn
                StackName: !Ref StackName
              RunOrder: '3'
```

My question is that how can I send the s3 object name to template file via codepipeline?
Or if there is any better way for lambda fucntion to get the updated s3 object?

I have searched pretty a lot and some posts talked about using "Fn::GetArtifactAtt" or saving the zipfilename to ssm and gets it from ssm, however i couldn't get them to work out.
forexample adding the following parameter doesn't seem correct as ObjectKey is the name of the .zip file that contains the artifact that is generated by CodePipeline not the name of the s3 object:

```
 ParameterOverrides: |
                  {
                    "S3Key" : { "Fn::GetArtifactAtt" : ["SrcOutput", "ObjectKey"]}
                  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several other ways to solve this issue potentially but in keeping with your current approach.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html

The first stage of a pipeline must contain at least one source action. You can declare it with a namespace like the following (SourceVariables):

```
        - Name: Checkout
          Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeStarSourceConnection
                Version: "1"
              Configuration: 
                ConnectionArn: !Ref CodeStarConnectionArn
                FullRepositoryId: !Ref BitBucketRepo
                BranchName: !Ref BitBucketRepoReleaseBranch
                OutputArtifactFormat: "CODE_ZIP"
              Name: Checkout
              Namespace: SourceVariables
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: !Ref SourceArtifactName
              RunOrder: 1
```

Within your pipeline definition '#{SourceVariables.CommitId}' can now be used e.g

```
 ParameterOverrides: !Sub |
               {
               "CommitId" : '#{SourceVariables.CommitId}'
               }
```

Then your CF template could be like:

```
Parameters:
 CommitId:
  Type: String


Resources:
 LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties: 
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref 'LambdaZipfileBucket'
        S3Key: !Sub lambda_function_${CommitId}.zip 
      Description: Monitor Lambda Function
      Handler: 'lambda_function.lambda_handler'
      Role: !GetAtt 
        - LambdaExecutionRole
        - Arn
      Runtime: python3.7  
      Environment:
        Variables:
           myvar1: "value1"
```

Comment: Thanks. this seems great. I will sure try this when I get another project. I went for another way on the project that I had.